# Python Pandas Statsmodel OLS issues

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have written the following function. The intention is to get the model which gives the right set of features with pvalues < 0.05
The function doesn't seem to be consistent results. In extreme cases it gives the results where of the pvalue are more than 0.9
Can someone help me here ?

```
def run_reg(X,Y,df):
    #Now lets start the regression model
    lreg = sm.OLS(Y,X)
    feature_count=1
    while(feature_count !=0):
        model = lreg.fit()
        pvalues = model.pvalues
        print(pvalues)
        feature_count= len(pvalues[pvalues > 0.05] )
        print(pvalues)
        if(feature_count != 0):
            pvalues = pvalues[pvalues < 0.05]
            pvalues = pvalues.drop('const',axis=0)
            X = df[pvalues.index]
            X = sm.add_constant(X)
            lreg = run_reg(X,Y)
    return model
```

Comment: What you are trying to do should recreate a reverse stepwise regression. What the code is missing is stopping criteria. So what is happening with your results is your model removes something with a low p-value, but that regressor was necessary to make the model work. [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/stopping-stepwise-why-stepwise-selection-is-bad-and-what-you-should-use-instead-90818b3f52df) does a much better job of explaining what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I read the article, but i am unable to understand how is adding/deleting one feature based on pvalue wold not work.
When i add/delete a new feature i run the the model from the start, as if the model is run for the 1st time.

Any inputs here?

Thanks